# xargs - No such file o directory - Jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, deployment, engineyard

I have a script running in my Jenkins to deploy my application to engineyard. My Jenkins environment have 'engineyard' gem installed.

```
first_customer_symbol=`bundle exec rake  customer:deploy_targets[$DEPLOY_TO] | sed '1!d'
ey status --account='account-****' --app="$first_customer_symbol" --environment="$DEPLOY_TO" | grep "Resolved Ref" | grep -Po "\b[0-9a-f]{5,40}\b" | xargs -i git diff --exit-code HEAD {} db/migrate 1> /dev/null
new_migrations=$?; if [ $new_migrations != 0 ]; then
bundle exec rake customer:deploy_targets[$DEPLOY_TO] | xargs -n1 -P 7 ey deploy -e $DEPLOY_TO -r $BRANCH_TO_DEPLOY --migrate -a
else
 bundle exec rake customer:deploy_targets[$DEPLOY_TO] | xargs -n1 -P 7 ey deploy -e $DEPLOY_TO -r $BRANCH_TO_DEPLOY --no-migrate -a
fi
```

I am getting an error

```
xargs: ey: No such file or directory
xargs: ey: No such file or directory
xargs: ey: No such file or directory
xargs: ey: No such file or directory
xargs: ey: No such file or directory
xargs: ey: No such file or directory
xargs: ey: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here. 
NOTE: I recently upgraded my Jenkins Ruby Version from 2.0.0 to 2.2.5 and restarted my Jenkins after which I started getting this error.

Comment: I don't have an answer. It does seem weird that the first `ey` on line 2 works fine, but not the others.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my jenkins instance, I had to install 'engineyard' gem again.

```
gem install engineyard
```

This solved my problem.